# Firebase cloud messaging notifications received but not popping up with capacitor/push-notifications

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Angular 13 Ionic 6 app I'm using the capacitor/push-notifications with FireBase,
In my service:

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {ActionPerformed, PushNotifications, PushNotificationSchema, Token} from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
import {  Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Dialogs, DialogType } from '../Utilities/dialogs';

import { get, set, remove } from './storage.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

//https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-capacitor/

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FbNotificationsService {

  onFCMTokenChanged: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

  tokenProcessed: boolean = false;

  
  constructor(private dialogs: Dialogs) {
    
   }
 
  initPush() {
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() !== 'web') {
      this.registerPush()
    } else {
      console.log('Web platform detected');
      this.onFCMTokenChanged.next('web-platform');
    }
  }
 
  private registerPush() {
    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then((permission) => {
      if (permission.receive === 'granted') {
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        console.log('FB Permission granted');
        PushNotifications.register(); //Registers app to receive notifications
      } else {
        // No permission for push granted by user on iOS
        console.log('FB NO permissions granted');
      }
    });
 
    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'registration',
      (token: Token) => {        
        if ((token)&&(!this.tokenProcessed)) {
          this.tokenProcessed = true;
          console.log('My token: ' + JSON.stringify(token));
          this.onFCMTokenChanged.next(token.value);

          set('device-token', token.value); 
        }
         
      });
 
      PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
        console.log('Registration Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        this.dialogs.dialogClose('Network Error','The network signal is not sufficient at this time. Please improve connection and try again');
        App.exitApp();
        
      });
 
    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationReceived',
      async (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        console.log('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
        alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
        //What to do next. Notification received on the device.
      }
    );
 
    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      async (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        const data = notification.notification.data;
        console.log('Action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification.notification));
        alert('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
        //What to do next. data holds all payload fields of the notification object
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The basic guide I followed is [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase).

When I send a test message from the Firebase console, the alert statement I placed is poping up, meaning, the message is received by the app:

```
alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification)); //WORKING
```

HOWEVER, there is no notification message popping up by the OS for the user to see. I do get notifications all the time from Whatapp, Emails, etc, and the "Do not disturb" setting is turned off.

This is experienced with TWO Android devices: Xiaomi Rednote 8 and Samsung Galaxy A32.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Mor. is your `pushNotificationActionPerformed` event getting triggered. In my case I am getting the notification but on clicking the notification nothing is happening.  It is not going into `pushNotificationActionPerformed` event. Can you help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before, maybe the following information could help you:

**When your Android app is in the foreground, PushNotifications won't appear on the screen.**

If you absolutely want a visual display of the notification, you can create a local notification when the push notification is received.